# How to set image size fix on jlabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

Hi I am trying to make  java desktop application  whee I am having a `JLabel` I am shuffling
image I want to set image size fit on that `JLabel`

Here is my code

```
public class ImageShuffle extends JPanel {

    private List<Icon> list = new ArrayList<Icon>();
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            update();
        }
    });

    public ImageShuffle() {
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
          list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\e.jpg"));
    list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\d.jpg"));
    list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\yellow.png"));
      list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\f.jpg"));
            list.add(new ImageIcon("E:\\SOFTWARE\\TrainPIS\\res\\drawable\\l.jpg"));
        label.setIcon(UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon"));

        timer.start();
    }

    private void update() {
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        label.setIcon(list.get(0));
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.add(label);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
```

How can i achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are your images different sizes?

Comment: yes images are different sizes

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18011430/2587435) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14553003/2587435)

Comment: in my code where i will have to make change

Comment: Read the answers from the links and try and figure it out. That's all part of learning.

Comment: Have a look in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856480/resizing-a-imageicon-in-a-jbutton

Comment: @anto can u suggest me where should i make change in my code

Comment: I guess inside the display() method

Answer (score 1):

Check out Darryl's [Stretch Icon](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) which will grow/shrink the Icon based on the space available in the label.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void display() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("ImageShuffle");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(this);
    f.add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setSize(x,y)
    f.setVisible(true);
```

X is ur width and y ur height!

If you write for example

```
  f.setSize(800,600);
```

It should set the size when you insert it like I did!

If you want to set the JLabel size it is like this:

```
 panelName.setSize(x,y);
 panelName.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: x and y will set size of frame?