# show more than one picture in a panel

Tags: java, image, swing, jpanel

I am trying to make a photo viewer ,and I meet some problem .

I want to show more than one pic once time in a Panel . But I could't do it well , in my project (you will see in pic1 ), it show all the pictures in a small space ,so all the picture become too small to see. I try to solve it by adding the GridLaout to  a JScrollPanel ,bu it could't work .

I want to know how to solve it , to show several pictures in a Panel once time.Not why I could't add a GridLaout to a JScrollPanel.

This is a part of my code[ It just a part and your could't use to to debug ,it's my idea of my project]

```
    grid = new GridLayout(0, 4);
    pane3.setLayout(grid);
    ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon("c:\\picture\\abc.jpg");
    JLabel tmp = new JLabel(ico);
    pane3.add(tmp);
```

If you know how to do it ,please contact me.Thans.

This is a good perform that I want to achieve

[image]

This one is my project perform ,it work baddly

[image]

Comment: Hi Huanfeng Xu, Welcome to Stack Overflow, please post your code for others to find the issue. Also, read below links [how to ask good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [not failing in explaing the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please don't be so casual in asking question!

Comment: I'm so sorry ,I would correct it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem you seem to be having, is you've not put your base component into a `JScrollPane`, so `GridLaout` has divided the available space evenly amongst the components.

See [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details.

You could also have a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010803/java-swing-resize-imageicon-according-to-jlabel/18011430#18011430) which does something simular